# Adding a filter search button to w2ui grid

Tags: javascript, w2ui

For my w2ui grid, I want to have a few search buttons to filter the data is pre-defined ways. (e.g. a "Big West" button to search for rows with "Big West" as the conference.

```
<button class="w2ui-btn" onclick="var obj = w2ui['grid']; obj.search({ field : 'conference', value : 'Big West', operator : 'contains', type: 'text' });">Big West</button>
```

When I click this button, the data doesn't change. Ideally, the first click would do the search, and clicking it again would take the search away.

Answer (score 0):

if you use w2ui grid it has wonderful search button , but you need to do customize in the data source file to filter rows I paste a script with
PHP and its work perfect for w2ui grid, and will simplify the whole process, and use it as backend with suitable customize for your work :

---

```
$action = $_REQUEST[request];
$action = json_decode($action, true);
 $vlimit = $action['limit'];
  $voffset = $action['offset'];
   $str = "";
    $err = "";
      $sql = "";
      switch ($action['cmd']) {
        case 'get':
        if (isset($action['search']) && is_array($action['search'])) {
            foreach ($action['search'] as $s => $search) {
                    if ($str != "")
                        $str .= " " . $action['searchLogic'] . " ";
                    $field = $search['field'];
                    switch (strtolower($search['operator'])) {

                        case 'begins':
                            $operator = "LIKE";
                            $value = "'" . $search['value'] . "%'";
                            break;

                        case 'ends':
                            $operator = "LIKE";
                            $value = "'%" . $search['value'] . "'";
                            break;

                        case 'contains':
                            $operator = "LIKE";
                            $value = "'%" . $search['value'] . "%'";
                            break;
                        case 'is':
                            $operator = "=";
                            if (!is_int($search['value']) && !is_float($search['value'])) {
                                //  $field = "LOWER($field)";
                                // $value = "LOWER('".$search['value']."')";
                                $value = "'" . $search['value'] . "'";
                            } else {
                                $value = "'" . $search['value'] . "'";
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'between':
                            $operator = "between";
                            $value = "'" . $search['value'][0] . "' and '" . $search['value'][1] . "'";
                            break;
                        case 'more':
                            $operator = ">";
                            $value = "'" . $search['value'] . "'";
                            break;
                        case 'less':
                            $operator = "<";
                            $value = "'" . $search['value'] . "'";
                            break;
                        default:
                            $operator = "=";
                            $value = "'" . $search['value'] . "'";
                    }
                    $str .= $field . " " . $operator . " " . $value;
                }

        $sql = "select *   from [table] "
                . " WHERE  ~search~  limit $vlimit offset $voffset ";
        $sql = str_ireplace("~search~", $str, $sql);

        }   
        else

        {
            $sql = "select *   from [table] ";


        }

        echo '{"status": "error","message":"' . $sql . '"}';
        break;
            $stm = $conn->query($sql);
            $result = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $number = $stm->rowCount();        
            $json = json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

            header("Content-type: application/json");
            echo '{"total" : "' . $number . '","records" : ' . $json . '}';

            break;




        case 'delete':

            $rec_id = $action['selected'][0];
            $sql = "DELETE FROM [table] WHERE rec_id =  :recid";

            $stmt = $accountdb->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam('recid', $rec_id);

           try {
                            $stmt->execute();
                           echo '{"status" : "success"}';
                           break;
                        } catch (Exception $err) {

                            echo '{"status": "error","message":"' . $err->getMessage() . '"}';
                            break;
                        }





        case 'save':
           /**/
            break;

        default:
            $err = 'default  error';
            echo '{"status": "error","message":"' . $err . '"}';

            break;}
```

[image]